# IE11 requires itself in order to install?

Tags: internet-explorer

I saw that IE11 has been released for Windows 7.

1. I opened my Internet Explorer
2. Searched for "download IE11"
3. Went to http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/ie.aspx?q=internet+explorer
4. Select the "Upgrade Your Browser" link, which directed me to [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie-MCM?FORM=MI09J9&OCID=MI09J9&WT.mc_id=MSCOM_EN_US_DLC_4PF_141B2ENUS51787)
5. Mashed the "Free download" button, which prompted me as to whether I wanted to run or save `EI11_EN-US_MCM_WIN764L.EXE`
6. To which I selected the Run button

Then I got this:

[image]

Why does Internet Explorer 11 requires itself in order to install?

It seems while eating their own dog food, the dogs starting chasing their own tails.

Comment: So what's your question?  If MS tested it?  We can't answer that.  If you're actually trying to figure out your IE11 install problem, then what steps have you already tried to rectify it?  Did you try downloading/installing it a second time (perhaps after a reboot)?  Anything in the Event Logs?

Comment: Download (save) the IE installation file - then remove all Internet Explorer versions under Start > Control Panel > Programs and Features > Installed updates. Then try to re-install.

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Rudolph - You can only uninstall Internet Explorer versions if you keep the installer and post people clean up that information.    More information about the troubleshooting steps Clay has done would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have the preview installed?

Comment: @ZippyV: No, I have version 10.0.9200.16721, update version 10.0.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Ramhound is right in his comment -- it's a bug in the installer currently linked on that page.

I just tried it and got the same result (Win7 64-bit, IE10 installed).

When I check the log (`c:\windows\ie11_main.log`) I see this:

```
00:00.000: INFO:    Setup installer for Internet Explorer: 11.0.9600.16428
00:00.000: INFO:    Previous version of Internet Explorer: 10.0.9200.16720
00:00.000: INFO:    Checking if iexplore.exe's current version is between 11.0.9600.0...
00:00.000: INFO:    ...and 11.1.0.0...
00:00.000: INFO:    Maximum version on which to run IEAK branding is: 11.1.0.0...
00:00.000: ERROR:   Internet Explorer version check failed.
```

Here's a link to the stand-alone IE11 installer:

[Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 64-bit Edition and Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40901)

I just downloaded, ran it, rebooted and it worked like a charm:

[image]

Comment: It did work for me with the exact same Windows and IE10 installed. It gave `00:00.327: INFO: iexplore.exe version check success. Install can proceed.`. Strange that in your version Windows can check in 00:00.000 seconds what version of IE is installed (while it took 00:00.327 for me). Either way, there something definitively wrong with the check.

Comment: @Rik Hopefully that means they fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling it from Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> View Installed Updates -> selecting Internet Explorer 11, reboot.  While you are at Programs and Features, remove any toolbars, coupon printers, free games, PC/registry cleaners, search protectors, search helpers, shopping buddies/shopping helpers, free video converters, free Youtube downloaders, or free security software that you don't actively use.

Disable any running antivirus or security software for the duration of the install, it could be interfering.

Download the installer, but save it instead of running it.  Then try running the installer again, but right click and select "Run As Administrator" this time.

If it does not work, look in Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer for clues on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the IE 11 setup in windows Safe mode.Worked for me

Comment: Why would this work? Supporting an answer with documentation is helpful in determining if it's applicable to a problem.